# What Locator or Command should I use to execute `type` on Redactor text editor?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-ide

I'm getting an issue when try to automated user type on [Redactor text editor](https://imperavi.com/redactor/).

Here's the details:

- Used command `click` or `clickAt` on Redactor text editor
- Used Locator with `ID`, `Name`, or `Class`.
- Used command `type` and input the text
- Used command `click` on Save button

All of the test case was PASSED, but no text typed/appear on Redactor text editor after click on Save button, why is that?

Comment: It seems somehow the text was sent to the wrong element and/or some internal Javascript event was not triggered. I had no problem automating/testing Redactor with [Kantu](https://kantu.io), but this one uses images as locator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely solvable

**Problem**: 
redactor editors usually work different way. You can use type or sendKeys IDE commands just for inputbox, which will inject the value of the inputbox.

Often text editors have generated id, which differs each time you reload the page

**Solution**: text editors usually define an element with an unique id, which contains subsequent/child HTML tags as content of the edited text. 
What you can do is to inject the value to this element by javaScript in storeEval.

**IDE code example**:
you will have to localise and replace the Xpath of the idOfTextArea stored variable

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td><p>Some text<br></p></td>
    <td>inputText</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>//div[contains(@id,'taTextElement')]@id</td>
    <td>idOfTextArea</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementById(storedVars['idOfTextArea']).innerHTML = storedVars['inputText']; </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementById(storedVars['idOfTextArea']).innerHTML</td>
    <td>resulttext</td>
</tr>
```

**Explanation**:

- By the `storeAttribute | //div[contains(@id,'taTextElement')]@id` you get the id of the editor window if it changes each time when you reload the page. If id of editor window is a constant, you can skip this point or replace it by `store | some ConstantId`
- By the `this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow()` you get current HTML document
- By the `getElementById(storedVars['idOfTextArea'])` you get the object of the editor Window. If the id of editor window element is a constant you can replace it instead `storedVars[...]` as well
- By the `.innerHTML` you get or change all HTML content in the editor window
- stored variable `resulttext` will contain the text if everything is ok, so you can validate the results if something went wrong by comparing both `inputtext` and `resulttext`